# Como criar um formulário de associação (PickList) em modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5, bootstrap

Como fazer a tela abaixo em modal.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Lembrando que as caixas são de múltipla seleção, e como fazer que ao clicar no botão `Associar >` passe para a coluna da direita os valores que selecionei na esquerda e vice-versa quando clicar em `< Desassociar`? Pode ser em jQuery ou JavaScript mesmo.

Comment: A pergunta do título não tem contexto com a dúvida do texto explanado. Veja aqui [como fazer um formulário modal em html utilizando o bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target).

Comment: O que eu quero é clicar em um botao em outra pagina minha e abrir esse modal, assim: eu clico no botao formulario na pagina inicio.html e abrir esse modal colocado no comentar.html

Comment: Tambem queria saber como organizar dessa forma pelo booststrap ja que fica bem desorganizado @ThiagoLunardi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Todo o processo é bem simples, primeiro você precisa ter dois select's com o atributo multiple e dois botões para realizar as associações, tudo que você vai fazer é pegar o item selecionado e adicionar no outro select e depois remover a option do anterior!

No bootstrap você poderá utilizar form-control para dar uma formatação adicional.

### Exemplo:

```js
var associar = $("#associar");
var desassociar = $("#desassociar");
var permissoes = $("#permissoes");
var minhasPermissoes = $("#minhasPermissoes");


associar.click(function() {
  var selecionado = permissoes.find('option:selected');
  minhasPermissoes.append('<option>' + selecionado.text() + '</option>');
  selecionado.remove();
});

desassociar.click(function() {
  var selecionado = minhasPermissoes.find('option:selected');
  permissoes.append('<option>' + selecionado.text() + '</option>');
  selecionado.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label>Permissões</label>
      <select id="permissoes" class="form-control" multiple>
        <option>Clientes</option>
        <option>Boletos</option>
        <option>Usuários</option>
        <option>Configurações</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label>Minhas Permissões</label>
      <select id="minhasPermissoes" class="form-control" multiple>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button id="associar" class="btn btn-primary">Associar</button>
  <button id="desassociar" class="btn btn-primary">Desassociar</button>

</div>
```

Veja funcionando também no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/nqa33d0k/4/)

Para adicionar em uma modal é muito simples também, a propria documentação do bootstrap tem excelentes exemplos disso.

Veja funcionando com modal no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/nqa33d0k/7/)

Documentação [Bootstrap-Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Você pode utilizar também um plugin que desenvolvi, basta incluir o pickList.js criar uma div e chamar `$("#pickList").pickList();`

[Github - Documentação](https://github.com/Gabrielr47/pickList)

[Exemplo jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/8ek53b1f/show/)