# Mudar destino do email ao clicar em uma opção do select em um formulário

Tags: javascript, select, email

Bom, eu tenho um formulário e preciso que ao selecionar uma opção do select mude:
1 linha - action
2 linha - value
 
3 linha - value
15 linha - Mudar onde está esta escrito enviaOrca2 para por exemplo enviaOrca1

```
<form id="formulario2" name="formulario2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="mail-lista-de-descontos.php"  >
        <input type="hidden" name="acao" id="acao" value="enviaOrca2" />
        <input type="hidden" name="mailTo" id="mailTo" value="email@email.com.br" />
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" data-required="1" data-title="E-mail" required>
        <label>Dia:</label>
        <select name="lista">
            <option value="Sexta15abril">Sexta 15 de Abril</option>
            <option value="Sábado16abril">Sábado 16 de Abril</option>
            <option value="Sexta22abril">Sexta 22 de Abril</option>
            <option value="Sábado23abril">Sábado 23 de Abril</option>
        </select>
        <label>Nomes Completos:</label>
        <textarea name="mensagem" id="mensagem" data-required="1" data-title="Mensagem" placeholder="Exemplo: João da silva, Tenório Antonio" ></textarea>
        <a href="javascript:enviaOrca2()" title="Enviar">Enviar</a>
    </form>
```

A única solução que eu achei foi esta abaixo só que eu não sei como faz para mudar várias opções ao mesmo tempo

```
<select id='seuSelect' onChange='alteraAction(this.value)' >

// seus options aqui, lembre-se, cada option deve ter um 'value'

</select>

function alteraAction(valor) { 
if (valor == "Segunda Opção") {
    $('#idFormulario').attr('action', 'novaaction.php');
   }
}
```

Comment: Da uma olhada @user4451  http://loudev.com/

Comment: Voce esta querendo um pickList? da uma olhada nesta minha resposta e ve se te ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114804/como-criar-um-formul%C3%A1rio-de-associa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-picklist-em-modal/114832#114832

Comment: Wellington Silva Ribeiro Eu entrei ai nesse site mas lá os códigos inserem e retiram de um container o que eu quero é apenas trocar o texto de algumas propriedades como action quando eu seleciono uma opção no select, isso por que cada opção do select vai para um email diferente

Comment: Gabriel Rodrigues Como eu disse para o willington apenas quero que o texto de certas propriedades do formulário mude conforme eu faça uma escolha no select

Answer (score 0):

Apenas acrescente a alteração que vc quer no function

```
function alteraAction(valor) { 
if (valor == "Segunda Opção") {
    $('#idFormulario').attr('action', 'novaaction.php');
    $('#email').val('email2@gmail.com');
   }
}
```

Comment: Nelson Teixeira tá mas são 3 opções então eu coloco um else if?

Comment: elseif, switch, for... como vc quiser